# Configuring RealVNC to accept copy/paste on a remote server

Tags: keyboard, vnc

So, I'm using RealVNC Viewer locally (Mac OSX 10.6) and connecting to a VNC Server on a remote machine (Debian - I'm no Unix expert).

I want to be able to copy and paste at the command line, but Ctrl+V, Shift+V and Command+V all do nothing on the remote command line. First question: should I be trying a different combination of keys?

Secondly, if it's not that I'm using the wrong combination of keys, how can I configure VNC Server to accept copy and paste?

I have 'Share clipboard with VNC Server' checked locally, so I figure it must be a problem on the remote machine.

I only have command-line access on the remote machine (though I am root) so I need to configure the option somehow via the command line.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://www.realvnc.com/pipermail/vnc-list/2004-August/046615.html) suggests running vncconfig with no parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the line you want rom your PC and then paste it with right click on your mouse button on your command line. I think it would work. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff is correct, at least on RealVNC's pro version the vncconfig, in addition to being a gui component, it also relays the clipboard activity.  I fyou have it up and cut-and-paste is not working, kill and restart it.

What I do not follow is (and this whole thing would have been a comment had I been able to post one) how do you expect to cut-and-paste in/from VNC if you only have command-line access?

This last comment, "*I only have command-line access on the remote machine*", makes no sense